# How to use capitals in subjects names?

Tags: subjects

I have seen subjects names like "Cognitive Sciences" are wrote both with and without capitals, like "cognitive sciences". Are there a criteria to this respect?

Comment: I think "Cognitive Science" refers to the cognitive approach to studying science, whereas "cognitive science" is ambiguous because it can also refer the scientific study of human cognition. I may be wrong 'cause I don't know much about Science. However, in most cases, the capitalization of proper nouns is just a matter of convention. In Linguistics, for example, some linguists distinguish between the language and Language.

Comment: @user178049 What pray tell is the difference between "language" and "Language"?

Comment: @CJ Language (capitalized) refers to the ability of humans to speak a particular language (Human Language Capacity). But a language (with the lower case) is an instantiation of this ability (eg. Malay, Arabic, English etc.). This from Andrew Carnie (2013: p. 5)

Comment: @user178049 I disagree that capitalisation has any bearing on the meaning of the word "language". Is Andrew Carnie's assertion viewable in context online?

Comment: @CJ Carnie's book is available at libgen.is, but it actually comes from [Chomsky's I-language vs E-language distinction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformational_grammar). The use of capitalization is actually quite confusing. I'd prefer the original terms with "I" and "E".

Comment: @user178049 I see no difference between their meaning and definition 2 at https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/language and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/language. I can't find any dictionaries that have a definition for "*L*anguage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to capitalise when it is simply the name of a subject or discipline.  In such a context it would be acting as a common noun, so would not need capitals.

It would be capitalised if referring to a specific course, department, etc, where it is acting as a proper noun.

*Professor Smith is a renowned expert in cognitive sciences.  Professor Smith works in the university's Cognitive Sciences department.  I am studying cognitive sciences as part of my degree.  My lecturer for the Cognitive Sciences module is Professor Smith.*